# Captions are better, yet validation loss is increasing

Tags: natural-language, computer-vision, seq2seq

I am training and validating an image captioning model with the following architecture:

- Encoder: ResNet-101 Pre-trained on ImageNet
- Decoder: GRU (1-Layer)
- Embeddings: Last BERT hidden state

I optimize the Cross Entropy at each time-step of caption generation on a vocabulary of size $|V|$. I evaluate my generated captions using the CIDER score which is a representative for better generated captions (I also checked the captions generated for validation split and they are actually good). Though the behavior of validation loss is strange:
[image]

As you see both the captioning metric and my loss are increasing. As I have never seen such a behavior from Cross Entropy, I am curious to know why this is happening!

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What dataset are you using? (type of data, size of the dataset, etc) I have seen the same behavior in image captioning myself, and I don't have an answer, but I think providing data info may be important to answer the question